# For what resources an explicit allow for the principal in a resource-based policy isn't enough to grant access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, identity-management

From AWS docs

`For most resources, you only need an explicit allow for the principal in either an identity-based policy or a resource-based policy to grant access. IAM role trust policies and KMS key policies are exceptions to this logic, because they must explicitly allow access for principals.`

it's clear that for **most** resources (that support resource-based policies), a resource-based policy is enough to grant access to an IAM principal (meaning, without the need to add an explicit **Allow**  to an identity-based policy of the principal). Trust policies and KMS policies are notable exceptions, since a resource-based policy *must* be attached to the resource.

Are there any other resources, where a standalone resource-based policy is not enough to grant access to an IAM principal? Or equivalently, are there any services where both an identity-based & resource-based policy at the same time is required to allow access?

The services I tried so far worked fine (S3, SQS, Lambda), but there are more than 20 services that support resource-based policies, so I can't check all of them.

I expect to be no service which supports resource-based policy and requires an identity-based changes to grant access to the particular resource.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of an explicit `Deny`, one valid<sup>*</sup> explicit `Allow` is sufficient:

> If either the identity-based policy or the resource-based policy within the same acccount allows the request and the other doesn't, the request is still allowed. [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policies_evaluation_example)

---

* Identity policies are valid for KMS only if the key (resource) policy explicitly [permits them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-default.html#key-policy-default-allow-root-enable-iam): *Unlike other AWS resource policies, an AWS KMS key policy does not automatically give permission to the account or any of its principals.*

Comment: I think that text is misleading, It's not true for KMS keys, for example.

Comment: @jarmod - Does the added footnote address your comment?

Comment: For KMS keys, yes. The OP is actually trying to uncover any other services/policies, of course.

Comment: thanks both, @fedonev indeed the point of my question is whether services other than KMS need a resource-based policy.

Comment: Not that I know of, although tomorrow AMS may introduce a service that does.  KMS _requires_ a resource policy because KMS (uniquely) also uses them as a [identity policy opt-in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/iam-policies.html) mechanism.  No key policy -> No IAM principal access.  However, from the [policy evaluation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow) point of view in the OP title and the answer, KMS is no exception.  Neither is a role trust policy, which does not grant service permissions.